Evaluate JavaScript with JSoup
As a response to my JSoup call I get a document like this
<body>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-a.js">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-b.js">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-c.js">
</body

In the browser the Javascripts are getting executed on runtime and I see valid HTML. Is there a way to make Jsoup execute the Javascript, so I see the HTML result? Thanks in advance for your help

It sounds like you want to use a headless browser (e.g. Selenium) instead of just a markup parser (e.g. JSoup).

Jsoup is only for parsing HTML, what you want here is a headless browser. If you must use java for this then your options here are:
htmlunit (but the javascript support isn't great, wouldn't reccomend it if the page has a non-trivial amount of js)
Selenium(browser automation, includes language bindings for Java)
